# IIF Expression in SSRS 2008R2

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

I have written an `IIF` statement:

```
=IIF(fields!addressline1.Value< ",", "No Details", Fields!addressline1.Value)
```

This works fine in that it returns **'no details'** if the addressline1 value is blank. However, I would also like to add fields!postcode.value to the initial argument, something like:

`=IIF(fields!addressline1.Value AND fields!postcode.value < ",", "No Details", Fields!addressline1.Value)` - but this isn't working.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify the "is blank" bit for each part of the And;

`=Iif(fields!addressline1.Value <"," And fields!postcode.value < ",", "No Details", Fields!addressline1.Value)`

As an aside, "less than a comma" is a super weird way of saying "is blank". I would expect IsNothing() to be used, so:

`=Iif(IsNothing(fields!addressline1.Value) And IsNothing(fields!postcode.value), "No Details", Fields!addressline1.Value)`

Of course if your way works, then I wouldn't worry.

Comment: I chuckled at the 'super weird' comment. I did try the IsNothing argument but even though the report was showing a blank field, something was clearly coming through from the field  (I have no idea what), which is why I used the strange <"," expression.  So basically it wasn't blank, it just appeared so in the report. Anyhow, your answers above have been very helpful and have sorted my end so many thanks for replying.